# Merge cells in column F, G based on a values in Column A

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for VBA code that looks at the values in column A and if they are the same, merges the cells in columns F & G in the same rows.

I have no idea how to do this.

[image: example]

Comment: A little add on if possible, i have tried but still to hard for me.  In g2 I would like it to sum H2, but then in G5 (the merged cell) i would like it to sum h5 to H9.  Is this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
Sub mergeFG()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range

    Set cell = Range("A2")
    Do While cell.Value <> ""
        Set cell2 = cell.Offset(1)
        Do While cell2.Value = cell.Value
            Set cell2 = cell2.Offset(1)
        Loop
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Resize(cell2.Row - cell.Row).Merge
        cell.Offset(0, 6).Resize(cell2.Row - cell.Row).Merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Set cell = cell2
    Loop
End Sub
```

Call `mergeFG`, either via other code, or link some button to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below. I have assumed that you have sorted Column-A i.e, ref_num and also change the SheetName from "Sample" in code to your workbook sheet name.

```
Sub merge_cells()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim counter As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample")
end_row = ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

counter = 1

For i = 2 To end_row

    If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = ws.Range("A" & i - 1).Value Then

        counter = counter + 1

    Else

        If counter > 1 Then

             ws.Range("F" & i - counter).Resize(counter).Merge
             ws.Range("G" & i - counter).Resize(counter).Merge

        End If

        counter = 1

    End If

 Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```